# Spring cloud kafka stream skipping lagged event

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, resilience4j

In my kafka stream consumer, I am using manual acknowledgement. I am also using `resilience4j` circuitbreaker.

In my circuit open state, I don't acknowledge the event and thus it increases the lag in my partition.

But when circuit goes to half open state and get ready to consume event, if at that time I produce a new event, that gets processed. And because this offset is higher than earlier events, the offset is also increased.

Thus, losing the events which were not acknowledged in open state.
Is there any solution to this problem if anyone has faced something similar